# Firebase console security & Firestore rules best practices

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

Looking for best practices info on securing Firebase console. I'm building an application with sensitive data in Firestore. We've got good rules around client access - but my concern is how to secure Firebase console. It doesn't seem that Firestore rules apply in console (I can understand that). But I haven't seen anyway to add granular security in console. It seems that if I give a user View access, they have everything.

Is there a way to get granular with what a console user has access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any security rules concept for Firebase console. You should only add authorized users to your Firebase project's team. If you need to restrict access without building a custom client yourself, try using a CMS like [Flamelink](https://flamelink.io/features).